# Terminal is asking for password while sudo command

Tags: command-line

I was trying to run a sudo command it is aksing for a password which password should i enter

Comment: The same password you used to login is the one you use for sudo.

Answer (score 1):

The password you enter for login. Sudo command gives you full access to all your files and documents so it needs to be sure that you are the owner of the computer. Sudo stands for "superuser do".